# How to improve StyleCop in check in?

Tags: tfs, stylecop, tfs-2012

I have VS2012 and local tfs2012 server. I need, when I check in code, some activity check code by StyleCop.

I need that not code that doesn't pass the rules in StyleCop doesn't get send to TFS. No check-in on build time.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate StyleCop with MSBuild so it will be run during every build of your project.

Have a look at the [documentation on the StyleCop project page](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setting%20Up%20StyleCop%20MSBuild%20Integration)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your build template to use the [StyleCop Activity included in the TFS Community Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20extensions%20into%20a%20build%20template&referringTitle=Documentation).  That's how I do it.